# Android Emulator starts but Eclipse doesn't recognize it

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

As a general rule, everything works fine, but then sometimes either Eclipse or my Android emulator decides to be a jerk and refuses to work.

I open the AVD Manager in Eclipse. I choose which AVD I want and click Start. The emulator starts up and it goes through the loooong process of booting. It finally finishes booting and then for some reason, it immediately reboots and goes through the looong process of booting again. Once it boots the second time, Eclipse loses track of it. It is no longer lists in the Devices tab and I can't install my app or run it on that emulator. If I kill the emulator and try to start it over, then I get the exact same behavior. It's incredibly frustrating.

There are no messages happening in the console to explain the behavior. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What versions of the Android SDK, ADT plugin, API level emulator, and Eclipse are you running?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That's a known issue when adb starts before the emulator. I don't know the real reason, but a quick workaround is to restart adb in the command prompt (with the emulator running)

```
> adb kill-server
> adb start-server
```

Now,

```
> adb devices
```

will return the emulator and Eclipse will be able to install the app.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led me to search terms which helped me find this site explaining the problem in detail. It includes a convenience shell alias to make this process easier: http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/android-disappearing-emulator-restart-adb-server/

Comment: `alias adb-restart` is a nice trick, it saves you a few seconds :) I never understood why there is no adb restart-server out of the box anyway. Notice that the adb devices command is not really necessary, and that this happens also on windows, not only linux. On ubuntu, this set of commands are useful when you want to access your actual phone with adb: `adb kill-server; sudo adb start-server` to get root access to the usb connection.

Comment: You can also do this from within Eclipse. Open the Devices view if it isn't open, and then select "Reset ADB" from the view menu (at the top of the Devices view).

Comment: @Aleadam: Just to mention that adb start-server will result in launching the server as a regular user and not as a root (unless root already) and this will make the device unrecognized by adb devices. running the adb start-server as root (ie with sudo) will correct that problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on my system (OS X 10.9.3, Eclipse Kepler 4.3.2). If I restart adb server from the command line, subsequently Eclipse couldn't start the app. Whereas if I reset the adb server from Eclipse, it crashes. with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Answer (score 13):

While in Eclipse, choose Window->Show View->Devices.

[image]

If you can't see the emulator on the newly opened window choose the down-arrow icon in the same window (near the minimize and maximize buttons) and from the dropdown menu select "Reset ADB".

[image]

The alternative is to open CMD.exe and type the following two commands (change the ADB directory as necessary):

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe kill-server
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this too. If you kill and restart the adb server, Eclipse should then see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
> ./adb kill-server
> ./adb start-server
```

tried these commands in mac os x / eclipse - works, but it also kills the actual devices and you have to unplug/plug them back in to get them back.