# Android OpenGL error during emulator launch

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have all the SDKs updated and all necessary components installed. My *code does not have any error* but whenever I launch any Android application in the emulator, I get the following error in the console. ***After that the emulator works normally and the application runs perfectly.***

**`Error :`**

```
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] ------------------------------
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] Android Launch!
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] Performing swayam.dev.mushtouch.MushTouchActivity activity launch
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Tablet_4.1' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-10-21 21:50:57 - MushTouch] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Tablet_4.1'
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - MushTouch] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-10-21 21:50:58 - MushTouch] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

After this, everything works perfectly. I know that this is not much of an hindrance to the application development as everything runs normally after this, but still I would like to know the reason behind this error. Am I missing any components ? Does my system not support anything ? What could be the possible reasons for the error ?

**My development environment :**
Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit, 
Eclispe Juno, 
JDK 1.6 and 1.7

Thanks!

Comment: read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12032761/925070 , it can help you

Comment: @dimetil : Thanks for the reply but still no luck.