# Emulator not running Windows XP

Tags: android, emulation

I am having the same problem, as the one specified under

[Emulator not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902685/emulator-not-running)

However, I use Windows XP, ADT v21.0.0-531062. In My AVD Manager, it is NOT possible to define any hardware options, as was the case with earlier ADT versions.

I have already set up an AVD, and whenever I start any of the sample applications shipped with "adt-bundle-windows-x86", I get the following error:

```
    [2012-12-23 19:37:33 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
    [2012-12-23 19:37:33 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES  emulation, using software renderer.
```

On my AVD, I have initially a black screen, after some seconds an "ANDROID" text appears, but nothing happens.

Below please find the result of starting the emulator from the console.

**Please help me!**

```
emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexand
er\.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.an
droid\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.
android\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.a
ndroid\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 17
emulator: 'magic' skin format detected: 720x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 720x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\
default.keyset
emulator: found magic skin width=720 height=1280 bpp=16
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/system-ima
ges\android-17\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/system-im
ages\android-17\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/sy
stem-images\android-17\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\av
d\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.androi
d\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\a
vd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\
avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 90MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 90
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\avd\Galaxy_
Nexus.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\a
vd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 720
  hw.lcd.height = 1280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 32
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/system-images\android-17
\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/system-images\andr
oid-17\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk/system
-images\android-17\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 204m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\av
d\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = Galaxy_Nexus
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-arm.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.android\avd\Gala
xy_Nexus.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-arm.exe -android-hw 'C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Alexander\.andro
id\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/hardware-qemu.ini'
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xcc00000,initfile=C:\Programme\adt-bundle-w
indows-x86\sdk/system-images\android-17\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to C:\DOKUME~1\ALEXAN~1\LOKALE~1\Temp\\And
roidEmulator\TMP56.tmp
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now cc0f000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Dokumente und Einstellun
gen\Alexander\.android\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '32m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen
\Alexander\.android\avd\Galaxy_Nexus.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: Can't start OpenGLES renderer?
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software rende
rer.
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS
1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.569531
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directo
ry
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: C:\Programme\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools\ddms.bat
emulator: ping command: C:\WINXP\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Programme\adt-bundle-wi
ndows-x86\sdk\tools\ddms.bat" ping emulator 21.0 "" "" ""
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
emulator: User-config was not changed.
```