# Android Emulator on Eclipse Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I've been following the instructions found at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html to run the Hello World app on Eclipse's AVD, but the AVD does not launch and I get the following messages:

```
[2013-01-20 00:20:59 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-01-20 00:20:59 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-01-20 00:20:59 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-20 00:20:59 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity      activity launch
[2013-01-20 00:21:00 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with     compatible AVD 'TestAVD'
[2013-01-20 00:21:00 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device    'TestAVD'
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] 
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-01-20 00:21:48 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Also, an error window popped up saying that the ARM emulator exe has stopped working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

OP of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902685/emulator-not-running) thread has similar error message,

> emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hm still not working. The OP of the other thread ended up solving it by upgrading his OS; he originally had a version of Ubuntu too old to run it. I'm using Vista so the OS (other than being inherently bad by just being Vista lol) shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check 2 things:

- That you are using 512MB of RAM (the emulator doesn't work properly
  with more)
- Try turning 'Host GPU' off

Answer (score 0):

Try running emulator from the command line with `GPU` option and make sure that it is working or not.

```
-gpu off
```

Even if it result into the error, go to the eclipse, Right Click on the project and select run my projects as an "Android application". Emulator should start.

You can also give a try with enabling/disabling `GPU emulation` option for the selected emulator from the AVD manager.

To enable/disable `GPU emulation` :

> Goto AVD manager -> select android virtual device -> click on Edit ->
>   Hardware tab -> enable/disable GPU emulation.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run an emulator with a higher resolution than I had my display set to.