# Android Emulator is not starting in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-11.04, eclipse-adt

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and i downloaded latest eclipse ADT bundle, i also have installed all `ia32libs`, i dont know why the emulator is not starting, i have tried various device configurations, i have 4 platforms 2.2, 2.3 , 4.0 ,4.2. i have tried various permutation and combination, but virtual device does not show up-none of them.

I have also tried various solutions in other SO'questions, they do not solve my problem. i have been **stuck in these for weeks**, still i have reached no where?Please Help

**FYI:** I also have eclipse Helios, in that it works fine but, i cannot get/download platform above 3.0/Honeycomb in that, and in the Helios the virtual devices work fine. i dont know whether its relevant or not, but still..

Comment: while launching whats it showing in console? any error message?

Comment: it does not show anything

Comment: try in your terminal as emulator -avd youremulatorname

Comment: I faced similar problem, I cant able to solve finally updating my OS helped. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11902685/1012284

Comment: yes @PadmaKumar i have been through this post and also starting via console worked, now i needed to set display config for my device, thnks a ton, you made my day, i wish can you give you bounty

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24816/discussion-between-padma-kumar-and-akhil-jain)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run your emulator in Command Line Parameters

To start an instance of the emulator from the command line, navigate to the `tools/` folder of the SDK. Enter emulator command like this:

```
emulator -avd <avd_name>
```

more about emulator [link here:](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Comment: I tried doing that and got this error :                                              `No command 'emulator' found, did you mean:` I'm using the ADT bundle..What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: @lnreddy   you didn't configure the SDK path tools in your system. or you can go to your sdk folder and do this cd /home/username/android-sdk/tools here you can find the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I configured it , and now I get a different error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: I'm using 64 bit adt bundle on my 64 bit Ubuntu ..So I tried it with `emulator-arm @test` and now it works . But it shows an error nevertheless. ` ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ok, now it starts from terminal ,but when I start it from eclipse , it doesn't start

Comment: use `emulator -list-avds` to get list of avds

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with a NVidia graphics card I had to do the following:

1. Install the SDK and ADT plugin for Eclipse
2. Install 32-bit libraries `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1`
3. Install OpenGL libraries `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`
4. Install proprietary drivers for the graphics card: System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers NVIDIA binary driver version 331.38
5. From Eclipse, run the Android Virtual Device Manager and edit a device. Enable "Use Host GPU" & save.

It then worked.

Comment: In case if answer above didn't help you, try to switch to `Software` -- this mode is recommended if you face any problems with your graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu Android Emulator Problem [Solved]

The issue with android emulator is not the hardware drivers. It is OpenGL drivers. To solve it please go through these steps:

1. Open synaptic package manager (If not please install it from Ubuntu software center)
2. In Quick filter type “opengl” and press search.
3. Select the following packages:
   `libgles1-mesa-dev`
   `libgles2-mesa-dev`
   `libgles1-mesa`
   `libgles2-mesa`
   `libqt4-opengl [Update/Upgrade]`
   `glmark2`
   `glmark2-es2`
   `libgles1-mesa-dbg`
   `libgles2-mesa-dbg`
   `freeglut3`
   `libhugs-opengl-bundled`
4. Selection procedure
       Right click on the package and select as ‘Mark for Installation”.
5. And click ‘Apply’.
6. Enjoy the ANDROID PROGRAMMING WITH THE EMULATOR.

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-Bit (installed the 32-bit libraries), 
My Case was :

1- downloaded and installed the SDK properly

2- download ADT plug in to Eclipse and restart it

3- set the SDK directory properly

4- create an Android project, and click RUN AS > Android application

5- asked me for an Emulator, so i created one from the AVD (after some steps from the Run Configurations)

6- then i Right-Click that application again, RUN AS > Android Application

7- a message appears > ERROR : Couldn's start Emulator ... install SDK properly (something like that)

8- Restart Eclipse ... every thing is fine !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the following option:
Edit your **avd** and change the "emulated performance" option to "software".

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Bumblebee` to disable my nvidia card...

It seems like Android Studio does not like that.

```
optirun /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

And then open AVD Manager in Android Studio made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://cialu.net/solve-android-studio-avd-issue-with-ubuntu-16-10/

```
   sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386

   sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

(look for the path of the sdk)

```
  cd YOURPATH/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64

  mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak

  ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

Finally, run your application again using emulator.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
If you are getting error like above then please update/upgrade your Linux Machine(Ubuntu) as for example

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get upgrade

and make sure that all as per [Android Developer](https://source.android.com/source/initializing#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1404) website all the required software are  installed.
 **If Still you are facing same issue as per image** then use su mode in your terminal before starting emulator. 
**sudo su -**  Use this command to be Su user

Answer (score 0):

Since Neither Ubuntu Support 32 bit nor Android Developers tools support 32 bit (Now and Legally) and also some having low end pc(s) like 512 mb ram, and for casually playing games for pc the best option for running android is ***Android X86***  . Its fast and always working android emulator(actually not emulator but an OS) you can use it for any thing even 20 years old pc can run it very very smoothly .

***To Run it in your any computer follow the below steps:***-

- Go to https://www.android-x86.org/
- Download any iso from there (i recommend for pc more than 512 mb ram =4.4 kitkat, and latest for more than 2gb ram(android 9.*) )
- Download Rufus or [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) (Etcher is recommended, Download Portable)
- Flash to Your Pen-drive or SD card
- Keep it Inserted and Restart
- You Will be On landing page (back to your pc ,[Click here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20boot%20from%20usb))
- Click on Live CD (if Dosen't work click on more option or VESA mode)