# AVD will not launch on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, emulation, android-virtual-device

I switched to Android-Studio a couple days ago, and I cannot get an AVD running no matter what I try. I've added the sdk path to my environment and have all permissions for the AVD. Whenever I try to start the Nexus 7 predefined AVD I created, the progress bar menu comes up, loads the entire bar and then does nothing. I have also tried waiting 30mins for it to start, but still nothing. I even have the JavaJDK installed and working. I have tried following several tutorials on how to setup the SDK and everything goes fine up until launching this AVD. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: please update the answer if solution is found

Comment: One of these solutions might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976353/android-emulator-is-not-starting-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

add 32bit library by typing bellow shell in your ubuntu 14.04 terminal:
**sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6**

[for more details:](http://dandar3.blogspot.mx/2014/03/android-sdk-tools-on-ubuntu-1404-beta.html)
http://dandar3.blogspot.mx/2014/03/android-sdk-tools-on-ubuntu-1404-beta.html

hope everything will work smoothly.