# how to remove emulator starting error

Tags: java, android, css, android-emulator, emulation

On Starting emulator for AVD 'hello' it shows Logcat Error:

```
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
RenderServer::create failed to listen
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
it seems too many emulator instances are running on this machine. Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually happen when you upgrade your ADT and SDK to the 20th version. For more details [Reffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902685/emulator-not-running).