# Android Emulator Couldn't Launch

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've managed to run android emulator through eclipse usually. But i don't know why the emulator couldn't launch for now. When i run it, i got message

> "Couldn't launch the emulator! Make sure the SDK directory is properly
>   setup and the emulator is not missing."

I can't figure out why this error happens since i never do anything with my sdk except that i ever move it to another directory and bring it back again.

I've found another question in SO similar to this but with a little difference in error message. And all of those answers don't solve my problem. I've tried launch the emulator from command line directly until i got this error message after the emulator shown and exit immediately.

> kahfi@kahfi-yanmii:~/sdk/tools$ ./emulator-arm -avd ginger-galaxy-mini
>
> emulator: ERROR: Could not load OpenGLES emulation library:
>   libOpenglRender.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation,
>   using software renderer. 
>   [xcb] Unknown sequence number while
>   processing queue 
>   [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and
>   XInitThreads has not been called 
>   [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
>   emulator-arm: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion
>   `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed. 
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: What do you mean by "i never do anything with my sdk except ... move it to another directory ..." that sounds like exactly the sort of thing that would break searches for libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message saying,

> "Could not load OpenGLES emulation library: libOpenglRender.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory"

It seems that file libOpenglRender.so not found. In this thread [Emulator not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902685/emulator-not-running), please look at user827992's answer that is probably related to your problem. Make sure the file exists and is readable and then write the directory path of the libraries into /etc/ld.so.conf.d/androidGL.conf.
I hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks i've tried and then i got difference error saying "error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I've check tools/lib directory and didn't find the file, but libGLES_CM_translator.so and libGLES_V2_translator.so.

Comment: the only way you can do is to download new SDK and then replace the old one. There should be something wrong with the libraries, or other files inside tools, platform-tools, or build-tools..

Answer (score 0):

You should install Genymotion. http://www.genymotion.com/

It is a system for managing and running Android emulators that are much faster than the ARM emulators you usually use, and it is simpler to use as well.