# emulator is not starting hanging on black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Recently i have upgraded my machine and starting with android studio i tried to create emulator but it is not starting it show black screen and hang there please help i tried to deleting emulator for nexus 5 and nexus 9 both show below error.

```
    C:\Users\gaurav\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus9
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Block size: 4096
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks per group: 32768
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inodes per group: 4224
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Inode size: 256
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
emulator: device fd:560
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
```

Comment: Use [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com) instead of android native emulator. It's faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the list of the system images in the second step when creating a new virtual device.  Are there mulitple entries with the same `ABI` **and** the same `Target`? (E.g. two items saying Lollipop, API Level 21 and ABI x86)

If so, try both of the entries - in my case, only the item with `Target` *Android 5.0.1* (and **not** *Google APIs (Google Inc.)...* ) works.

Also try enabling (disabling) the `Use GPU host` option in the third step of the process, and maybe try to re-install HAX (even though your log says it's working fine)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

just give it some time? how long have you waited?

try the solutions here

[Emulator not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902685/emulator-not-running)

Comment: i have waited more than 2 hours.

Comment: check the link, if you try some of the solutions there I am sure it will work... As it is the same problem you are having. You said you upgraded, and now your using Android Studio, did the emulator work on Elcipse if you had it before ?