# android mobile device is not showing on device chooser of eclipse

Tags: java, android

After spending a lot of time, this issue is not solved. I am using karbonn a+1, and after installing all drivers and running `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, and then `adb devices`, it is not showing the device on device chooser.

Comment: `USB debugging` enabled on the device?

Comment: Enable USB debugging. If it is already done, you may want to restart your phone and computer once. Helped in my case.

Comment: also You need device drivers installed for karbonn device

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12598872/1514026

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable 'USB debugging' on your device?

You can find this setting in the Development settings. If you need need information on how to enable it, check [the android manual on using hardware devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Comment: i did several time this but still no progress i think it may be driver problem

Answer (score 1):

It can be because the driver isn't installed.

- Go to Device Manager from Control Panel.

Now if there are some driver under Android Phone, then other setting might have caused that. Else, if your Android show small yellow mark, there is problem with the driver.

- Right Click on that 'android' button
- click Update driver and chose latest driver from computer.

That should work. If you have bought new phone, like Karbonn, and you are tried of searching adb driver online, like I was, its actually on your own phone. Navigate to SD-Card on your phone and copy 'Pcdriver' to your desktop. Unzip it and update your driver selecting. Hope this helps.

If you on Windows 8, you may have to Disable Driver Signing before that:

1. Move your mouse pointer to the upper right-hand side of your
   monitor. This will open the charm bar.
2. Click the Settings charm.
3. Click the Change PC settings link at the bottom of the Settings
   menu.
4. Click the Restart now button.
5. Click Troubleshoot.
6. Click Advanced Options.
7. Click the Startup Settings.
8. Click the Restart button. Your computer will reboot.
9. After the reboot, press the [F7] key. This chooses the 7) Disable
   driver signature enforcement option.
10. Login to Windows 8.

Comment: If anyone has problem please feel free! I'd same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

- Right click on your project.
- select run as -> Run configurations.
- `select tab` target - > Choose always prompt to pick device.

this may solve your problem. :)

Comment: i did several time this but still not solved it may be driver problem i think so

Answer (score 0):

You have to walk through these steps if you have an Android device from a small manufacturer with custom usb id.

- Download the Google USB driver (Android SDK Manager -> Extras)
- Find your device in Control panel -> Device manager
- Click on Properties->Details and select Hardware identifier property. You should see something like USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&REV_0222&MI_01
- Change sdk/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf

Copy

> ```
> ;Google Nexus One
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
> ```

add new entry for your tablet. Change the VID and PID to your device's. (The ones in step 2.)

> ```
> ;Orion Tablet
> %SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010
> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_2207&PID_0010&MI_01
> ```

- Add the VID of the device to the end of
  Users/%user%/.android/adb_usb.ini . Take care to the 0x hexa
  notation!

> ```
> # ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
> # USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
> # 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
> 0x2207
> ```

- Remove all existing device drivers for the device
- Turn on USB Debugging on your device
- Plug in the device
- Select manual installation of the driver
- Select the driver from sdk/extras/google/usb_driver
- Select Android Composite ADB Interface
- Run adb kill-server
- Run adb devices

Your device should show now up in the device list.